# Is there common code to load a SWF in Flash CS and Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, load, flash, flash-cs5

It seems that in Flash, you can load an SWF (CS-built) with **Loader**. To load the same (CS-built) SWF in Flex, you need **SWFLoader**.

The thing is, I am creating an SWF-loading framework and I want it to be cross-compatible, both with Flash CS and Flex. Is this possible, or do I need 2 versions of my code?

Comment: Loader should work in Flex too.  I think a SWF Loader is just a layer of Abstraction above Loader; which makes it easier to use inside of a Flex app.

Comment: You can use Loader in Flex only if the SWF is a child of UIComponent : http://blog.pixelingene.com/2008/06/use-the-swfloader-for-loading-flash-swf-into-flex/
But is it possible to create an mx.core.UIComponent from within Flash IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use the SWFLoader class with (at least) CS5.5; you need to download the Flex SDK and declare the Flex libraries for use inside the authoring tool.

In other words, you have to add this path inside the "Library Paths":
...\flexsdk\frameworks\libs

then you can use all Flex libraries with CS5.5.